# Permutate basic BNF style string

Tags: c, bnf

I want to find all permutations for very simple BNF-alike style strings.

The only operators are `()[]|`

so `()` for "must have" `[]` for "optional" and `|` for "or"

So given a string `(foo | bar) [zop] [flip | flop]`

It would give me the following result:

- foo flip
- foo zop flip
- foo zop flop
- foo flop
- bar flip
- bar zop flip
- bar zop flop
- bar flop
- foo zop
- bar zop
- foo
- bar

Are there any algorithms that I can employ to do this? I can write a simple parser + tokenizer but my gut feeling there is probably a simpler solution. I'm coding this up in ISO C.

Comment: `foo`, `bar`, `foo zop`, and `bar zop` would be results as well, no?

Comment: With this language, I think it should be easy to transfer this to a DFA?

Comment: @SeanBright you're right! missed those. Edited. Thanks!

Comment: Is the exact syntax as seen in your example a requirement? Is C (as tagged) a requirement? If not, then [join](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/join.1.html) will do the job: `join -j99 <(tr "|" "\n" <<<"foo|bar") <(tr "|" "\n" <<<"|zop") | join -j99 - <(tr "|" "\n" <<<"|flip|flop")`

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to use recursion with string parsing. So for each character:

1. If it start with '[' handle mandatory set
2. If it start with '(' handle optional set
3. Otherwise just jump to next closing braket ')' or ']'

Handling mandatory and optional sets is getting its tokens and iterating over them and repiting 3 steps above. Also handling optional set has one empty iteration to not include anthing as its optional. So:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_SIZE 1024

void printPermutation(char* result[], int size) {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
                printf("%s ", result[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
}

void parseDeep(char* s, char* result[], int currIdx) {
    char* mandatory[1024];
    char* optional[1024];
    char *start = 0, *end = 0;
    char* delim = "|";
    int mandatorySize = 0;
    int optionalSize = 0;

    while (*s != 0) {
            //Mandatory
            if ('(' == *s) {
                ++s;
                end = start = s;
                while (*end != ')') {
                        ++end;
                }
                char* mandatorySet = malloc(end - start + 1);
                strncpy(mandatorySet, start, end - start);
                mandatorySet[end - start] = 0;

                char* token = strtok(mandatorySet, delim);
                while (token != 0) {
                        mandatory[mandatorySize] = malloc(strlen(token) + 1);
                        strcpy(mandatory[mandatorySize++], token);
                        token = strtok(0, delim);
                }
                for (int m = 0; m < mandatorySize; ++m) {
                        result[currIdx] = mandatory[m];
                        parseDeep(end, result, currIdx + 1);
                }
                for (int i=0; i < mandatorySize; ++i) {
                    free(mandatory[i]);
                }
                free(mandatorySet);
                s = end;
                return;
            //Optional
            } else if ('[' == *s) {
                ++s;
                end = start = s;
                while (*end != ']') {
                        ++end;
                }
                char* optionalSet = malloc(end - start + 1);
                strncpy(optionalSet, start, end - start);
                optionalSet[end - start] = 0;

                char* token = strtok(optionalSet, delim);
                while (token != 0) {
                        optional[optionalSize] = malloc(strlen(token) + 1);
                        strcpy(optional[optionalSize++], token);
                        token = strtok(0, delim);
                }
                for (int m = -1; m < optionalSize; ++m) {
                        //Optional when it is not added
                        if (m == -1) {
                            continue;
                        } else {
                            result[currIdx] = optional[m];
                            parseDeep(end, result, currIdx + 1);
                        }

                }
                for (int i=0; i < optionalSize; ++i) {
                    free(optional[i]);
                }
                free(optionalSet);
                s = end;
            }
            mandatorySize = optionalSize = 0;
            ++s;
        }
    printPermutation(result, currIdx);
}

void parse(char* s) {
        char* result[MAX_SIZE];
        parseDeep(s, result, 0);
}


int main() {
    char *s = "(foo | bar) [zop] [flip | flop]";
    parse(s);
}
```

This does not check validity of the string.